# Clip raster by raster with data extraction and resolution change

Tags: qgis, raster, r, clip, resolution

I need to stack multiple maps (tif) together and **clip them all according to extent of one small raster map** (second raster at the top of picture below). However, the **size of pixels in each map is different**. Is there any way how to make process visualized bellow?

Please, answer only R-solution or QGIS-solution.

[image]

```
library(raster)
e1<-extent(c(0,6,0,6))
r1<-raster(nrows=3,ncols=3,ext=e1)
values(r1)<-c(0,4,1,0,1,1,1,2,3)
plot(r1)
e2<-extent(c(2,5,2,5))
r2<-raster(nrows=4,ncols=3,ext=e2)
values(r2)<-c(0,8,2,1,4,9,9,4,0,8,0,0)
plot(r2)
```

Comment: Steps to take: (1) Resample both rasters to same samplesize (2) Unify their extents ether by cropping or extending (3) Stack them and mask with your other raster

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can:

Load required libraries:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
```

Read rasters:

```
r1 = raster("./dir/r1.tif")
r2 = raster("./dir/r2.tif")
```

Resample to the finer grid

```
r.new = resample(r1, r2, "bilinear")
```

If required (for masking), set extents to match

```
ex = extent(r1)
r2 = crop(r2, ex)
```

Removed unrequired data

```
r.new = mask(r.new, r2)
```